# pass error parameter in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I am using a third party framework, in which it contains a class :

```
class DaService : NSObject {
    init!(name username: String!, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>)
    …
}
```

In my swift code, I create an instance of `DaService`:

```
let service = DaService(name: “My Name”, &err)
```

Compiler complains:

`Use of unresolved identifier ‘err’`

Why this error? How to pass an error parameter in swift ?

Comment: That should be documented in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html).

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but `var err : NSString? = nil` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test it currently, but it should be

```
var err : NSString? = nil
let service = DaService(name: "My Name", &err)
```

More information can be found in the "Autoreleasing Pointers" section in [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).

Answer (score 0):

you haven't initialized err before passing it. Working example:

```
class DaService : NSObject {
    init!(name username: String!, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>) {}

}

var err: NSString? = nil

let service = DaService(name: "My Name", error: &err)
```

Of course, better use swift2's `throws` and `do/catch` for error handling.

Comment: But the parameter is not `inout` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

@MartinR is correct. `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>` means that the function intends to provide a NSString to you. You must give it a variable in which to put the string.

```
var errorString: NSString?
let service = DaService(name: "My Name", error: &errorString)
```